# Declare and assign an amount of variables from an input?

Tags: python, variables, input

Looking back into my previous calculator project I made in python I wanted to improve on it. I noticed that the amount of numbers to use were hard coded and could only pick to use 2-4 numbers and so on.

I want a solution where I can take the user input on how many numbers he will desire to use and have the program respond to this and create the correct amount of variables with each value.

Here this program takes in 2 variables from 1 input:

```
    v1, v2 = input("Enter 2 nums!").split()
    print("var1 = ", v1, "\nvar2 =", v2)

    v1, v2 = [int(v1), int(v2)]
    ans = v1 + v2

    print("Sum =",ans)
```

Though this does a useful job for multiple inputs, it does not achieve my set goal. Would it be somehow possible to have these 'v1', 'v2' variables automatically created depending on how many 'splits' it does or how many variables it finds.

For example if amount_of_vars = 3, then it would create 3 variables from the input and so on depending on the variable 'amount_of_vars'.

Comment: why not just use a list variable `v = input().split()` and use it like `v[1]` for first var, `v[2]` for second and...

Comment: Wow thanks, looks like I haven't done my share of homework about the .split with inputs. Though would it be possible to know how many v[x] were created?

Comment: You mean the length of a `list`? Sure, with `len(mylist)`. But you don't even need that here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `list` variable:

```
v = input().split()
```

Than use `v[1]` for first value, `v[2]` for second value , `v[3]` for third ...etc.

To convert all values to `int`:

```
v = [int(x) for x in v]
```

To do the sum:

```
s = sum(v)
```

To know the number of values:

```
l = len(v)
```

Comment: and if the task is just to get the sum of a list you might just be able to do `sum(v)`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to unpack certain hard-coded variables plus an uncertain number of additional ones, you would use the `*` operator (only in Python 3):

```
first, second, *myvars = input("Enter 2 nums!").split()
```

You would then have a variable `first`, a second variable `second`, and a `list` of additional variables in `myvars`. If there were only two numbers, `myvars` would be an empty `list`.

However, since you don't want a certain minimum number of variables, you can do this:

```
myvars = input("Enter 2 nums!").split()
```

`myvars` will be the `list` returned by `split()`.

Finally, you can find the sum of numbers with the built-in function `sum()`:

```
myvars = input("Enter 2 nums!").split()
print('var{} = {}'.format(idx+1, num) for idx, num in enumerate(myvars))

print("Sum =", sum(map(int, myvars)))
```

Comment: You should specify that `first, second, *myvars` usage only works for Python 3.x

Comment: The OP is using parentheses around the printed content, so they're probably using 3.x. It's not certain, but it's likely.